# how to do the projection of JSON data using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
{
    "ClaimType": ["The length of 'Claim Type' must be at least 4 characters. You entered 2 characters."],
    "ClaimValue": ["The length of 'Claim Value' must be at least 4 characters. You entered 1 characters."],
    "Description": ["The length of 'Description' must be at least 10 characters. You entered 6 characters."]
}
```

I am getting the response from Web API as mentioned above. How can I project the data using typescript as mentioned below?

expected result array of strings:

```
["The length of 'Claim Type' must be at least 4 characters. You entered 2 characters.",
"The length of 'Claim Value' must be at least 4 characters. You entered 1 characters.",
"The length of 'Description' must be at least 10 characters. You entered 6 characters."]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "project the data"?

Comment: sorry for the typo. let me correct it.

Comment: @Aaron does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the initial object is stored in the `data` variable.

```
Object.keys(data)
 .map(key => data[key])
 .reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], [])
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `Object.keys` is to directly use `Object.values`:

`Object.values(yourData).reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], [])`

Or another alternative:

`[].concat(...Object.values(yourData));`

Comment: I am new to typescript world, what is this ...acc? Is it syntax?

Comment: This solution uses [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). You can combine them to do some pretty powerful object manipulation

Answer (score 0):

You can map your keys data into array as below example.

```
let ApiData ={
    "ClaimType": ["The length of 'Claim Type' must be at least 4 characters. You entered 2 characters."],
    "ClaimValue": ["The length of 'Claim Value' must be at least 4 characters. You entered 1 characters."],
    "Description": ["The length of 'Description' must be at least 10 characters. You entered 6 characters."]
}
let Array= Object.keys(ApiData)
    .map(key => ApiData[key])
    .reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr], []);
console.log(Array);
```

Comment: did you just copy my solution as posted it as your own?

Comment: before any suggestion you should write some example to understand user.